# Pass a variable with POST method in <map> area?

Tags: php, html, post, get

I'm a newbie in web developing.

I'm currently working on a webpage, that has a mapped picture. I'll post a fragment of the code, so you know what I'm talking about.

```
 <AREA SHAPE=POLYGON HREF='front.php?area=104' ALT="104"  TARGET="_self" COORDS="47,205, 78,237, 93,222, 63,190, 47,205">
```

As you can see, I'm passing the variable I want through GET method.
I'd like to change to POST method, as I think it's more secure and I'm planning to do queries on my MySQL database with the variable I get from that map. (GET is easy to tamper just by adjusting the url, right?)

I googled myself, I searched in stackoverflow too, but I couldn't find anything similar. I'm looking to do this only with HTML, PHP and MySQL. I'm not really familiar with Java or Ajax and if the solution requires one of those, I ask you to use extra detail!

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: "(GET is easy to tamper just by adjusting the url, right?)" - Post is unsafe too, since you're handling user inputs anyway. http://bobby-tables.com to learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. You can only transmit data by post if you post a html-form (normally done by a user). GET is the right approach for you, you only need to use prepared statements and everything is fine ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Will those suffice??
$myusername = htmlspecialchars($myusername);
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $myusername);

I use those ready statements for my login forms well. Are they enough?

Comment: No. You should really use prepared statements. Simply google for it, you'll find a lot of examples on how they work. Another question: Do you store passwords in plaintext in your database, or do you hash them before? That would also be a really important part.

Comment: They are plain text and I will look into that before "releasing" the app. It's a small app to be used by 5-10 people in the business. Is it much of a safety risk? Also, be aware that I haven't built the website from scratch. I'm just improving/correcting.

Comment: Saving passwords in plaintext is actually a huge risk. You should use password_hash() to hash the password before saving. Then use password_verify() to check if its correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JQuery` for this task.

```js
$(".some-class").on("click", function(e) {
  // disabling default event handler
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).attr("ALT");
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    url: "your-url.php",
    ...
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<AREA CLASS="some-class" SHAPE=POLYGON HREF='#' ALT="104" TARGET="_self" COORDS="47,205, 78,237, 93,222, 63,190, 47,205">
```

For security, you also need to use a secret key (token), which you will substitute into some hidden field on the page. The key must be generated at random for each user session. When user sending data, you should check whether the key passed to you by the user is the same. Google more: csrf token defence.

Comment: Thanks. After the conversation I had with Twinfriends, I'll keep the GET method. However, your answer is pretty straight-forward and to the point and of course I'll accept it as the one that solves my query. I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Thanks again!

Comment: @StathisGer. np man ) However, I updated my answer. You can read about the methods used to protect your server in the last paragraph. The best way to protect your data is to use POST + TOKEN.

Comment: I did see that! I took it under consideration. :)